# How can I compare the product version of a remote .exe file against a known value?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powershell-remoting, invoke-command, fileversioninfo

I'm trying to use the following code to compare a file's version to a specified version and tell me which one is higher.

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\reviewfileversion\servers.txt"
$versioupdated = "16.11.32106.195"
foreach ($server in $servers) {

    $version = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" | ForEach-Object { $_.VersionInfo.productversion }

        If ($version -eq $versioupdated) {
            Write-Host "updated"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "no updated"
        }
    }
}
```

The result that it always tells me is that it is "updated", even if I change the version of the variable `$versionupdated`.

I have tried putting it like this:

- ```powershell
  If($version -eq $versioupdated)
  ```
- ```powershell
  If($version -eq 16.11.32106.195)
  ```
- ```powershell
  If($version -eq "16.11.32106.195")
  ```

And the same but with `-match`, `-like` and trying with different comparators.

I have read some help from this forum, but they have not worked for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show what `$version` is if you just run that script block? Are you sure that `invoke-command` is executing correctly on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a typographical error or a logical error, but I will reformat your code a bit so the problem is more evident...

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\reviewfileversion\servers.txt"
$versioupdated = "16.11.32106.195"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $version = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
            | ForEach-Object { $_.VersionInfo.productversion }

        If ($version -eq $versioupdated) {
            Write-Host "updated"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "no updated"
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's clear that the `-ScriptBlock` parameter encompasses not just the `Get-ChildItem ... | ForEach-Object ...` pipeline but also the `If...else...` block that follows.

## Local session variables in a remote `[ScriptBlock]`

The pipeline is yielding the `VersionInfo.ProductVersion` property of the `devenv.exe` file, which will be assigned to the *local* variable `$version`, but you can't then use that same variable in *remote* code...

```powershell
If ($version -eq $versioupdated) {
```

`$versioupdated` is also only defined *locally*, so that comparison becomes effectively...

```powershell
If ($null -eq $null) {
```

...which is always `$true`.

The shortest path to making your code work is to simply move one closing brace such that the remote code only obtains the `ProductVersion` property and the local code performs the actual comparison...

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\reviewfileversion\servers.txt"
$versioupdated = "16.11.32106.195"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $version = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
            | ForEach-Object { $_.VersionInfo.productversion }
    }

    If ($version -eq $versioupdated) {
        Write-Host "updated"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "no updated"
    }
}
```

If you really did want to perform the comparison remotely you could define `$versioupdated` inside the `[ScriptBlock]` so it is a remote variable...

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\reviewfileversion\servers.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        $versioupdated = "16.11.32106.195"

        # Get-ChildItem is unnecessary when retrieving a single file
        $file = Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

        If ($file.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -eq $versioupdated) {
            Write-Host "updated"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "no updated"
        }
    }
}
```

...or as above but just compare against the string literal instead...

```powershell
If ($file.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -eq "16.11.32106.195") {
    Write-Host "updated"
}
else {
    Write-Host "no updated"
}
```

...or define it as a local variable and pass it as parameter to the `[ScriptBlock]` using `-ArgumentList`...

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\reviewfileversion\servers.txt"
$versioupdated = "16.11.32106.195"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList $versioupdated -ScriptBlock {
        param($requiredVersion)

        # Get-ChildItem is unnecessary when retrieving a single file
        $file = Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

        If ($file.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -eq $requiredVersion) {
            Write-Host "updated"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "no updated"
        }
    }
}
```

...or specify the [`Using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) to identify the variable as coming from the local session...

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\reviewfileversion\servers.txt"
$versioupdated = "16.11.32106.195"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        # Get-ChildItem is unnecessary when retrieving a single file
        $file = Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

        If ($file.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -eq $Using:versioupdated) {
            Write-Host "updated"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "no updated"
        }
    }
}
```

## Comparing version strings

You also mentioned that you want to...

> ... compare a file's version to a specified version and tell me which one is higher.

Comparing `[String]` instances with the `-eq` operator, of course, will only tell you if the `[String]`s are identical.  You probably won't bump into it with the `[FileVersionInfo]` class, but `[String]` comparisons will give you undesirable results for cases like this...

```powershell
PS> '1.2.3.4' -eq '01.02.03.04'
False
```

...or this...

```powershell
PS> '1.0.0.0', '2.0.0.0', '10.0.0.0' | Sort-Object
1.0.0.0
10.0.0.0
2.0.0.0
```

Instead, convert your version `[String]`s to instances of the [`[Version]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.version), which knows how to compare each component of the version...

```powershell
PS> [Version] '1.2.3.4' -eq [Version] '01.02.03.04'
True
```

...as well as determine ordering...

```powershell
PS> '1.0.0.0', '2.0.0.0', '10.0.0.0' | Sort-Object -Property { [Version] $_ }
1.0.0.0
2.0.0.0
10.0.0.0
```

You can incorporate `[Version]` comparisons into your code like this...

```powershell
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\reviewfileversion\servers.txt"
[Version] $versioupdated = "16.11.32106.195"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        # Get-ChildItem is unnecessary when retrieving a single file
        $file = Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
        [Version] $fileProductVersion = $file.VersionInfo.ProductVersion

        If ($fileProductVersion -eq $Using:versioupdated) {
            Write-Host "same"
        }
        elseif ($fileProductVersion -gt $Using:versioupdated) {
            Write-Host "newer"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "older"
        }
    }
}
```